# Enable compression, Minify JavaScript rails 3.1 in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, minify, pagespeed, assets

Hi Guys I am checking the page speed from my web page in development mode with plugin for mozilla firefox **page speed** for firebug.

I want to know if is possible Enable compression and Minify JavaScript in development environment mode in rails 3.1

I put this screenshot that problem that page speed show:

[image]

My page speed is very slow 52/100, then I want to know if can I enable compression and minify javascript in development mode.

Thank you

Comment: Problem Fixed, you must put the server in production Mode for fix this problem with page speed!